# ng-model two way binding not working with ui bootstrap modal

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have following code for working with ui bootstrap modal. I am having a input field whose value has to be captured on the controller. But the input field value is not getting reflected on the controller after an value is entered on the modal.

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$modal', function($scope, $modal) {

    $scope.openModal = function() {
        $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'modal.html',
            controller: BoardController
        });
    };
}])

.directive('modalDialog', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        template:
            '<div class="modal-content">' +
                '<div class="modal-header">' +
                '<h4 ng-bind="dialogTitle"></h4>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div class="modal-body" ng-transclude></div>' +
                '<div class="modal-footer">' +
                '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ' +
                'ng-click="cancel()">Close</button>' +
            '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ' +
                'ng-click="ok()">Save</button>' +
                '</div>' +
            '</div>'
    };
});

var BoardController = function ($scope, $modalInstance) {
    $scope.dialogTitle = 'Create new item';
    $scope.placeholder = 'Enter item name';
    $scope.inputname = '';

    $scope.ok = function () {

        console.log($scope.inputname);
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };

    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
};
```

In 'modal.html' i have the following code:

```
<modal-dialog>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="enter-name"
           ng-model="inputname" placeholder={{placeholder}}>
    {{ inputname }}
</modal-dialog>
```

So, after entering some text into the inputfield when i click the save the following line under $scope.ok() prints `blank`.

> console.log($scope.inputname);

I guess this has something to do with scopes or may be transclusion. But i am not able to figure out whats causing this. I couldnt find the updated value in developer console also.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is transclusion. [`ngTransclude`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude) directive creates one more scope, but it is a *sibling* scope. Using transclusion makes it very difficult to access your scope. In your case you could retrieve model value like this:

```
$scope.ok = function () {
    console.log($scope.$$childHead.$$nextSibling.inputname);
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
};
```

But of course this is terrible. Fortunately, you can control what scope transclusion will use for rendered template if you make transclusion manually. For this you need to use `link` function with the fifth argument which is transclude function.

Your directive will become (note, that you don't use `ng-tranclude` directive in template anymore):

```
.directive('modalDialog', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        template:
            '<div class="modal-content">' +
                '<div class="modal-header">' +
                    '<h4 ng-bind="dialogTitle"></h4>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div class="modal-body"></div>' +
                '<div class="modal-footer">' +
                    '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="cancel()">Close</button>' +
                    '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">Save</button>' +
                '</div>' +
            '</div>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller, transclude) {
            transclude(scope, function(clone) {
                var modalBody = element[0].querySelector('.modal-body');
                angular.element(modalBody).append(clone);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/I7baOyjx4pKUJHNkxkDh?p=preview

Comment: Thanks. I have decided to go without transclusion for now :)

Comment: I would also avoid it if possible. But now you know how it works more or less.

Comment: Yes certainly. I can use them better in future.